# Prove: Every collection of r subsets each with atleast $|X|(1-\frac{1}{r})$ points of X has a non empty intersection.

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I am unable to show this "trivial" fact:

Let $X$ be a finite set. Then every family of subsets of $X$ of size $r \ge 2$, where each subset contains atleast $|X|(1-\frac{1}{r})$ points of $X$ has a non-empty intersection in X.

My only idea was to use the inclusion-exclusion principle. So if $A_i$ are the r sets, then:
\begin{align*}
|\cup_i A_i| \le \sum_i |A_i| + (-1)^{r+1} |\cap_i A_i|
\end{align*}
which gives nothing.

Comment: What you want to prove is not true. Let $r=2$, let $X=\{1,2\}$, and let the family of subsets contain $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$. Each subset has at least $|X|(1-\frac1r)$ points of $X$, but the intersection is empty.

Comment: It's as simple as taking to complements of your set. If $\mathcal F$ is your family of sets, then define $$\mathcal G=\{X\setminus S\mid S\in\mathcal F\}.$$ Then each element of $G$ has size at most $|X|/r.$ It won't necessarily be true if all elements are of size $|X|/r,$ however. You will need at least one set in $\mathcal G$ of size less than $|X|/r,$ or, equivalently, one set in $\mathcal F$ of size greater than $|X|(1-1/r).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews , Mike Earnest Yup, got it, thanks. I don't know why it didnt occur to take complements.